# How to access parameters of current Asp.Net MVC Action while OnActionExecuted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to access/intercept a controller action and getting its parameters and values. For example my action is;

```
   public virtual JsonResult ProductAutoCompleteResult(string term, string moduleName)
    {
        var requestDTO = this.portalServiceClient.CreateRequestDTO<ProductRequestDTO>();
        requestDTO.Filter.Keyword = term;
        requestDTO.ModuleName = moduleName;

        ProductResponseDTO responseDTO =this.portalServiceClient.Channel.GetProductsByProductCategoryTypeCode(requestDTO);
        base.CheckResponse(responseDTO);
        var products = Mapper.Map<ICollection<ProductModel>>(responseDTO.Products);

        var result = products.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(term))
            .Select(x => new { id = x.ProductId, value = x.Name });
        return new JsonResult { Data = result, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

In here, I want to access *responseDTO*'s values while OnActionExecuted event and after filled responseDTO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model` and cast it to the corresponding type if used in an action filter. In case of overriding OnActionExecuted on the controller, either `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model` or `ViewData.Model` property can be used.